# Is Java Array list trimToSize() method redundant?

Tags: java, arraylist

I think `trimToSize()` method in Java's ArrayList is unnecessary. My understanding is:

Let's take an array of integers:

```
int[] a = new int[10]; //This allocates ten free slots proactively.
```

The major advantage of ArrayList is it can create arrays dynamically at run time thus saving memory. Now the code
`ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);` will not assign ten free slots proactively; instead it adds slots only when there is data to be stored.

Now Java specification says `trimToSize()` will remove the unused space from ArrayList, but according to my understanding there won't be any unused space in ArrayList because space is created only when data is available, and when data is available the unused or free space will be nil.

Comment: An ArrayList actually allocates substantially more space than it needs every time it runs out of space, so it won't have to allocate immediately when it grows again.

Comment: Incidentally, what did you think `new ArrayList<Integer>(10)` was doing with that `10` argument, if not preallocating 10 slots?

Comment: *walks out since @user2357112 took his comment twice in a row*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect. If you create a `new ArrayList<Integer>(10)`, it will create an array of Integer of size 10 filled with nulls inside of the ArrayList as the nucleus of its data model. It will fill some or all of the slots depending on the number of items, and it will increase the size of the underlying array if the number of items exceeds its number of possible size. The `trimToSize()` method has relevance.

Comment: Nope I don't think it's right an arraylist of size 10 has a potential to store ten elements but it wont be allocated without data available.

Comment: The underlying array will be of size `10`, e.g. `Integer[10]`. Unused space is considered null, but is allocated. Having to recopy all data to a new array upon each insertion would take a massive amount of computation

Comment: @user1613360: [Here's the source for the Java 7 version.](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28int%29) Read it, and you'll see it really does allocate 10 slots.

Answer (score 5):

Redundant: no. Useful? Only in very specific situations.

What you should know is that an `ArrayList` increases the backing array when it's filled with a certain ratio of elements.

[what stood here previously was used for a `Map`, not an `ArrayList`]

An `ArrayList` internally will check every time an item is added whether or not it should resize the backing array:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
}

private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
        grow(minCapacity);
}

private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}
```

I left out some things that were mostly boundary checks. So as you can see: when it runs out of space to add an item, it will create a new array 1.5 times the size of the previous one and add all items to it. For an initial value of 10 items, it will go immediately to 15 afterwards.

Extrapolate this to much higher values and you can see that you suddenly start allocating thousands of empty array entries when you might be about done with adding items.

Likewise the removal of values might cause your backing array of 10 million elements to shrink to 10 elements. It's rather wasteful to allocate several million array entries when you only need a dozen.

Comment: ArrayLists don't have load factors. You're thinking of HashMaps.

Comment: Arraylists start with 10 (or 15, but 15 might be for Maps or Sets) and double every time.

Comment: @AnubianNoob: it starts with 10, but I believe it only becomes 150% the new size instead of doubling.